# Leiningen in Ubuntu 13.10 won't work

Tags: ubuntu, clojure

I have upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.10, and now I can't seem to use leiningen.

I have project that I was working on before upgrade, and all dependencies I have added before upgrade, are working, but now I have added `plaza` to work with RDF, but I keep getting `FileNotFoundException`.

When I try to REPL `lein deps` I get following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: lein in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:42) 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: deps in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lein deps` is a command you run at the shell (for instance, Bash), not at the REPL. When you type `lein deps` at the REPL Clojure looks for vars named `lein` and `deps` but they don't exist - thus the error.

If you've declared a new dependency in your `project.clj`, simply close the REPL you currently have open and then run `lein repl` again from within your project directory. It will install the dependency and open a new REPL, where you'll then be able to access that dependency (as well as the ones you installed previously).